# strange php upload issue with non image files causing 403 submisson error why? - image files ok

Tags: php

got this strange situation:

my php script correctly uploads image files and renames them as long as they are the designated, png/gif/jpeg files.

BUT! when i upload a non image file eg. .php or .html [ for testing / hackers ] the first upload is rejected as expected and my own constucted error is issued - so far so good but this is what happens next if:

1) i upload the nxt/2nd file, if the next file is a permitted image file no problems.
2) i upload the next/2nd file AND if this 2nd file is also non-permitted image file ie. two-consequetive non-allowed uploads the script stops execution with the correct recall of the script/url in the browser with a 403 - submision error ???

- if i do browser refresh, same 403 error persists.
- if i click into url and press return the script runs 'a new' with all previous field values being emptied.

( i have changed the permission on the non-image files being uploaded to 777 just to enusre that this is not the cause - but same error persists )

how do i resolve this???
- could this be my problem with my own code?
- or a problem with html/php internal workings?
- what else could this be, any body faced similar probs??

thank you.

--- for those who wants the code - showing just the important bits..

```
<form name="sellerscript" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" name="upload3" id="f3" size="40" />
<input value="Image Upload/Adjust" name="imgupload" type="submit"> <br>

<input type="hidden" name="turn" value="<?php echo $round;?>" />
<input name="fn3h" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $fn3; ?>"  />
    <input name="uf3h" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $uf3; ?>"  />
```

--- php --

//================  UPLOAD FILES VARS =[ only foto/image 3 used ===========

$allowed = array( 'image/gif' , 'image/png' , 'image/jpeg' , 'image/pjpeg' );
        $fname=$fname2=$fname3='';
        $uploaded1=$uploaded2=$uploaded3=$auto_insertid=FALSE;

```
    $uid1=$uid2=$uid3='';       // id for uploads table

    $currentf1=$currentf2=$currentf3=''; //-- present loaded fname
```

//-- upload processing

if ( !isset($_POST['rmp3']) && $removep3h!='Yes') //not enter whn prev.file.beng remvd
{

```
//-- echo '<br>image 3 being uploaded:name+'.$_FILES['upload3']['name'].'<br>' ;
```

if (  isset($_FILES['upload3']) )
{

if ( ( ($_FILES['upload3']['name']!="" ) || ($_FILES['upload3']['name']!=NULL ) ) &&  ($_FILES['upload3']['size'] <= 1524288 ) )
{
        $uf3=$_FILES['upload3']['name']; // users own name of last uploaded file;

```
//--echo "<br> _________ file under 520k --upload permitted file---------";
```

///////////////////////////////

above all seems to be working except: when two files that are othher than png/gif/jpeg uploaded consequetive one after the next - the 403 error occurs.

files are:
[root@myhost Desktop]# ls -l *.png
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27342 Oct 30 18:46 a1-banner5.png
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31812 Nov 11 23:31 a1-credit.png #
-rwxrwxrwx 1 arif arif 1418 Oct  8  2011 2851auto.gif
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2321 Oct  8  2011 btf2.gif

-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46321 Oct 22 23:35 ez-calc.html

-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25958 Oct 25 23:58 dixonhome.html
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24883 Oct 26 00:01 dixons-home.html

note: all image files upload in all sequences without problems except [a1-banner5.png] - this prodouces same issue if it is uploaded AS THE 2ND FILE following a non-image upload ie. 403 error.
other hrml files being yploaded consequitively produce 403 error.

files uploded from:
drwxr-xr-x 26 root www-data    4096 Feb 13 20:38 Desktop
files uploaded to:
drwxrwxrw- 2 www-data www-data  4096 Feb 17 23:45 uploads
temporary directory:
drwxrwxrwx  47 root www-data 12288 Feb 18 00:25 tmp  (tried root as the grp - same err)

error:url + 403

www.testdomain/domainsite/sellerscript.php

403 Forbidden
Access to this resource on the server is denied! 
Powered By LiteSpeed Web Server
LiteSpeed Technologies is not responsible for administration and contents of this web site!

---

also when script runs perfect with image only uploads:
url:

wwww.testdomain/domainsite/sellerscript.php

The file > Photo-3/btf2.gif has been uploaded!

[ note: both urls are the same !]

i hope this is enough iformation for someone to spot the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: atleast, I didn't get it...what you actually want to ask? whats your code?

Comment: How about you show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, check your permissions, if you can search in the directory and your read/write rights.